# Using ANTLR4 in Python to parse math expressions

Tags: python, antlr4

I am new to ANTLR4 and I am trying to use ANTLR to parse the fraction expressions in Python and then change them to the structure understandable to Python. The main reason behind using this instead of regex is the recursion for nested patterns.

The structure of a fraction in my case is `\\frac{a}{b}` and my desired format is `(a/b)`. There are similar projects done already like Latex2Sympy but I am trying to understand how it works.

The parser can find the match in python. For example for `\frac{1}{2}` it returns `(result_ (expr (fraction \frac { 1 } { 2 })))`. The result is coming from a "tree", can I extract parts of it like the numbers (1 and 2) and then substitute them in a `(1/2)` form?

Here is the grammar file I generated:

```
grammar frac_gram;

options{
    language=Python3;
}

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

result_    :   expr+ ;
expr       :   fraction;

integer :   INT;
fraction:   FRAC L_BRACE integer R_BRACE L_BRACE integer R_BRACE;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

FRAC:  '\\frac';
L_BRACE: '{';
R_BRACE: '}';
INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

The Python code:

```
import sys
from antlr4 import *
from antlr4.InputStream import InputStream
from frac_gram_grammarLexer import frac_gram_grammarLexer
from frac_gram_grammarParser import frac_gram_grammarParser
from frac_gram_grammarVisitor import frac_gram_grammarVisitor

def main(argv):
    input_stream = InputStream(argv)
    lexer = frac_gram_grammarLexer(input_stream)
    token_stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = frac_gram_grammarParser(token_stream)

    tree = parser.result_()

    lisp_tree_str = tree.toStringTree(recog=parser)
    print(lisp_tree_str)

    visitor = frac_gram_grammarVisitor()
    visitor.visit(tree)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('\\frac{1}{2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searches I found the solution is to name the numerator and denominator part in the grammar file, i.e.

```
fraction:   FRAC L_BRACE upper=integer R_BRACE L_BRACE lower=integer R_BRACE;
```

So, I name the numerator as upper and denominator as lower and then it can be extracted in Python after it gets parsed by the ANTLR parser by its attributes

```
def convert_fraction(result_of_parser):
   #print(result_of_parser.toStringTree())
   numerator_ = result_of_parser.upper
   denominator_ = result_of_parser.lower
   return sympy.Mul(numerator_ , sympy.Pow(denominator_ , -1, evaluate=False), evaluate=False)
```